# How to configure puppet so that it installs yum repos with debug mode?

Tags: yum, puppet

When i run `puppet apply`, it tries to install packages using the following command:

```
/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install couchdb-1.2.0-7.el6
```

How can i configure so that it runs it as following instead:

```
/usr/bin/yum -y install couchdb-1.2.0-7.el6
```

That is, without removing the debug logs?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a module with an exec resource in it.

```
>  exec { 
> 
>           "couchdb":
>            command => "/usr/bin/yum -y -d 0 install couchdb-1.2.0-7.el6",
>            path => "/usr/local/bin/:/bin/", 
> 
> }
```

as a test I did an update to my wget.  Before running the module wget was at 1.11.4-2.el5. In my repository I had 1.11.4-3.el5_8.1.

Here are the results of my 'yum update list wget.x86_64':

```
Installed Packages
wget.x86_64                1.11.4-2.el5                             installed

Available Packages   
wget.x86_64                1.11.4-3.el5_8.1                         update
```

this is my puppet output after applying the class (with a debug option to show you the ouput):

> debug: Executing '/usr/bin/yum -y -d 0 update wget.x86_64' notice:
>   /Stage[main]/Yum-update-test/Exec[wget]/returns: executed successfully

And this is the output of the 'yum update list wget.x86_64' after the class/module was applied:

```
Installed Packages
wget.x86_64                1.11.4-3.el5_8.1                            installed
```

Comment: The problem with exec approach is that it won't be idempotent. Every run will execute this command. On the other hand, the package resource command of puppet won't execute this if it detects this package is already installed (which is good). You can consider using the creates/only-if/unless attributes of exec to perform conditional execution.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for a real fix thru this ticket:
https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3453

Your only solution is to modify directly the yum package provider:
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/provider/package/yum.rb

```
  def install
wanted = @resource[:name]
# If not allowing virtual packages, do a query to ensure a real package exists
unless @resource.allow_virtual?
  yum *['-d', '0', '-e', '0', '-y', install_options, :list, wanted].compact
end
```

Change the '-d' value to 10 and you'll be done

Answer (score 0):

If you provide yum the `-d` or `-e` options multiple times, it will use the most recent values. So, you can also use `install_options` on your package resources. For example:

```
package { 'wget':
  install_options => ['-d' , '10' , '-e' , '1' , '-v'],
}
```

your puppet log will then include something like:

```
2017-10-19 14:02:48 +0000 Puppet (debug): Executing: '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y -d 10 -e 1 -v install wget'
```

... and all of the debug output.